# How to build up a json value within angular template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have such element within my template:

```
value="{{option.id}}"
```

I want to turn the param value into a json object using template literals

```
value="{{`id: ${option.id}, field: ${otherParam}`}}"
```

So the value would looks like `{ id: 'bla', field: 'other' }`, is it possible to do that?

I also tried {{ JSON.parse(....)} } by creating a component variable `JSON = JSON` but still having difficulties using template literals.

Comment: Do you mind giving feedback on my answer to see whether I just misunderstood your question?

Comment: try ```value="id: {{option.id}}, field: {{otherParam}}"```

Answer (score 0):

There is JSON.stringify(yourObject)

see documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: It does not work because of not able to use template literals (backticks)

Comment: you shouldn't! JSON.stringify(...) make a string of your object. Build the object as you want: *JSON.stringify({id: option.id, field: otherParam})*

Comment: the problem is a string literals

Comment: how would you form the `yourObject` using template literals withing an angular template?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. But you should not pass a string to `value` attribute in your case. Instead bind to value using `[]` in order to bind custom objects:

```
[value]="{id: option.id, field: otherParam}"
```

**Note:** You can use any variables you like in this binding, which are available in this context. This can be either other HTML tags (referenced by `#`), public variables from your component or dynamically defined ones (like variables defined in parent `*ngFor` directive).